# Why are extra RGB colors appearing in PyOpenGL generated bitmap image?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, pyopengl

Using Python and OpenGL, I'm creating a simple red triangle of RGBA = (1,0,0,1) and saving it as a bmp. I then load the image using CV2 and extract the RGBA colors that can be seen.

**I want the red color and the background color to be the only colors in the image.**

This code isn't pretty but successfully generates and save the triangle image as bmp:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2


VERTEX_SHADER = """
#version 330

in vec4 position;

void main() {
    
    gl_Position = position;
    
    }

"""

FRAGMENT_SHADER = """
#version 330

void main() {
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    }

"""

shaderProgram = None
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 200,200
def initialize():
    global VERTEX_SHADER
    global FRAGMENT_SHADER
    global shaderProgram
    
    vertexshader   = shaders.compileShader(VERTEX_SHADER,   GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentshader = shaders.compileShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    
    shaderProgram = shaders.compileProgram(vertexshader, fragmentshader)
    
    triangles = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                 0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]
    
    triangles = np.array(triangles, dtype=np.float32)
    
    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.nbytes, triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    
    position = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position")
    glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(position)
    
    
def render():
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3)
    glUseProgram(0)
    
    # Save a screenshot
    screenshot_file_path = 'test.bmp'
    data = glReadPixels(0,0,200,200, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    image = Image.frombytes('RGBA',(200, 200), data)
    image.save(screenshot_file_path, 'bmp')
    print('Image saved to ' + screenshot_file_path)
    
    glutSwapBuffers()
        
        
def main():
    glutInit()
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200)
    glutCreateWindow("Modern Opengl Triangle")
    initialize()
    glutDisplayFunc(render)    
    glutMainLoop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**But when I parse the image's colors, I see 3 RGB triplets! rather than the expected 2.**

Image parsing code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
imgfile = r"test.bmp"

npimg = cv2.imread(imgfile)

# cv2 reads the file into BGR, but we want to see the color as RGB
npimg = cv2.cvtColor(npimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Get unique RGB colors
uniqueRGB, uniqueRGBcounts = np.unique(npimg.reshape(-1, npimg.shape[2]), axis=0, return_counts=True)

print(uniqueRGB)
```

Result is:

```
[[  0   0   0]  <- Background
[188   0   0]  <- ??? some other red
[255   0   0]] <-  Desired red
```

What is going on? Can anyone explain where the extra triplet comes from? More importantly, how to make sure that ONLY the (255,0,0) and background (0,0,0) RGBs are saved to the bmp image?

Comment: First thing which comes to mind is that you have set your graphics driver anti-alias settings to forced or "enhance" . However, you really want to use an offscreen FBO for your use case, pixels which aren't visible on the screen will have undefined values otherwise.

Comment: @derhass thanks for the insight. I hadn't considered any graphics driver settings. Will look into that. I agree with using the offscreen buffer.

Comment: @derhass I disabled anti-aliasing settings in NVIDIA control panel and I'm still seeing an extra RGB after re-generating and parsing the image. After disabling anti-aliasing, the extra RGB triplet changed from [188,0,0] to [127,0,0]. Not sure what to make of that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @derhass had suggested, it was due to anti-aliasing. In my comment above I didn't completely turn off anti-aliasing and was still seeing weird results. After disabling it completely, I only have my desired red and background colors in my bitmap!

So, for any other noobs dabbling in image generation where you need to specify or read the exact colors in an image, make sure anti-aliasing is disabled!

EDIT: *To the comment below suggesting I provide more detail on how to disable anti-aliasing:*

I believe it's going to depend on whatever GPU or graphics drivers are in use. I have an NVIDIA GPU so I changed my settings using the NVIDIA Control Panel Application. Any feature referencing "Antialiasing" was changed to the off setting. Here's a screenshot of my NVIDIA control panel (3D settings tab) settings
[image: CP]

Comment: This would be a better answer if you gave details on how to definitively disable anti-aliasing.